# Empty string value returned when returns variable is not named in declaration

Tags: solidity, string

I'm trying to implement a simple "pop" function in solidity, and I am getting very different behaviour with string values depending on whether or not I name the `returns` value in the function declaration.

```
contract PopArray {
    string[] public string_arr;

    function PopArray() {
        // fill the array with some data
        string_arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
    }

    // Calling this once returns 'four', calling it a second time returns 'three', etc. 
    function pop_string () returns (string member) {
        member = string_arr[string_arr.length-1]; //get the last value
        string_arr.length = string_arr.length-1;  // reduce the length of the array
        return member;
    } 

    // Calling this returns nothing, but does reduce the length of the array.
    function broken_pop_string () returns (string) {
        string member = string_arr[string_arr.length-1];
        string_arr.length = string_arr.length-1;
        return member;
    }
}
```

Here is how the results look in remix when I call one function, then the other : [image]

Conversely, with other types I've checked, a value is returned regardless of whether the return value is named in the function declaration. [Here is some code](https://gist.github.com/maurelian/2a8ff9b1f7e3d8c69374f751af960633) trying this out with `uint` and `bytes32` values.

Is there a subtlety regarding strings that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I'm not mistaken,* the subtlety you've hit upon is Reference variables, because `member` is going to be a pointer instead of a unique memory var as you might expect.

Again, *if I'm not mistaken*, after you shorten the array, the reference pointer refers to a non-existent member of the array, so some unexpected behavior.

See here: http://vessenes.com/solidity-frustrations-references-and-mapping/

These Reference types emerge when the value requires further analysis, e.g. array index or mapping index. You get a pointer to an existing value instead of a new named variable/value.

Comment: Thank you, it seems you are right. Logging the value of `member` before and after shortening the array verifies it. 

Also, adding `memory` fixes the behaviour so that the string value is returned. (ie. `string memory member = string_arr[string_arr.length-1];`)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your observations. It's quite useful as this subtlety leads to non-obvious outcomes. From PV - "We are in a world where a tiny code error may not be easily fixable. In that world, this is a very annoying language feature, one that could cause real problems."

Comment: I'm still a little confused actually. This part of your answer makes sense to me: 

> These Reference types emerge when the value requires further analysis, e.g. array index or mapping index.

But then why shouldn't variables pointing to an array element containing a `bool`, `uint`, and `bytes32` not behave the same way? I can't find any reference to this difference in the docs, so am tempted to characterize this inconsistency as a bug. What do you think?

Comment: I might urge you to do that. Even a "not a bug" explanation might provide some clarification. I'd be a big fan if that sort of clarity turned up in this thread. I'm certain a lot of Solidity devs are unsure about this. It seems rather important to understand.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1812